# Is there a better way to get the specific element by their class name to modify the elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select a specific element so that I can delete or change the content of the element.

For example, if this is the code I have

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "a"> OPTION 12 </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "b"> OPTION 78 </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "c"> OPTION 56 </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "d"> OPTION 90 </div>
</div>
```

If the order of the box gets rendered randomly when loading up a page, and I want to select a div that has OPTION 56  and delete the whole node that contains that content, what is the best way to approach this WHEN they render in the webpages randomly?

I know you can remove the childNodes with getElementsByClassName and their indices. Is there a specific way to access the node/element without using the getElementsByClassName method?

I've tried adding an id for all each of the div classes.

I want to select a parent div that contains the content OPTION 56 and delete the whole

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "c"> OPTION 56 </div>
</div>
```

Parent node.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's many `div` tags that are not closed in tour example

Comment: Use id then `getElementById('YOURID')`

Answer (score 2):

You can always put the value of the div into a data attribute.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="a" data-option="OPTION 12">OPTION 12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="c" data-option="OPTION 56">OPTION 56</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your javascript (or jquery, as using below) would involve

```
$('[data-option="OPTION 56"]').parent('.box').remove();
```

Comment: this solution involves using jQuery. Just so OP knows that.

Comment: @Iwolf I saw the jquery tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not know the class name beforehand and only know the `innerText` value you want to remove, you can do this to remove the element:

```js
const removeMe = "OPTION 56";
const e = document.querySelectorAll('.container .box div');

e.forEach(e => (e.innerText === removeMe && e.remove()));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="a"> OPTION 12 </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="b"> OPTION 78 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="c"> OPTION 56 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="d"> OPTION 90 </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery's [:contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to fined the element with the desired text:
   `$("div:contains('OPTION 56')")`
   (you can make it more specific by adding its parents in the selector).
2. Use jQuery's [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to go to its parents.
3. Use jQuery's [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the "grandfather" node.

Here is a sample code:

```js
$("div.container > div.box > div:contains('OPTION 56')").parent().parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "a"> OPTION 12 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "b"> OPTION 78 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "c"> OPTION 56 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class = "d"> OPTION 90 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution in javascript can  resolve your problem.
You have this kind of structure

```
           <div id="options-container">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class = "a"> OPTION 12 </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class = "b"> OPTION 78 </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class = "c"> OPTION 56 </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class = "d"> OPTION 90 </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have given id *options-container* to the parent div. Then applied this solution

```
var options = document.getElementById('options-container');
              var childElements = options.childNodes;
               childElements.forEach(function(child) {
                  if((child.innerText) === "OPTION 56") {
                     child.remove();
                  }
              });
```

It dynamically remove every child which will have value *OPTION 56*.
I hope it will help you ;)